# How to read and store a cell value for use in Sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a script that retrieves all events from a Calendar and places them into a sheet. I'm trying to make this script dynamic by referencing cell B2 in the active sheet, so that I can change the calendar ID without needing to jump into the Script tool every time.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
var mycal = "IDNUMBERHERE@group.calendar.google.com"; 

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);   

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2017 23:59:59 CST"), new Date("January 1, 2018 23:59:59 CST"));
```

NEW CODE:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue()); 

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2017 23:59:59 CST"), new Date("January 1, 2018 23:59:59 CST"));
```

Running the new code, I keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null." I'm guessing it has something to do with me 'var cal' not being set up correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue());  to check that the value you get is actually the calendar ID

Comment: You could possibly use a prompt like this `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Calendar ID', 'Enter Calendar ID', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK)`

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I substitute my own calendar id into a test sheet. I would also suggest that you look into the PropertiesService for storing document variables: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious, this was solved by simply doing the following.

```
  var mycal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("c2").getValue(); // PULL CALENDAR ID FROM CELL
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Try changing getValue() with getDisplayValue()